# Office 2010 & Windows 7 - 'File' is currently in use. Try again later

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office-2010

The issue: when saving a document from either Word, Excel or PowerPoint 2010, every so often it will show the message **'file' is currently in use. Try again later.**

We started our rollout of Windows 7 beginning of this year, and this issue was infrequent, but is now affecting enough people to be a problem.

Usually, if you clear the alert, then save again, it works fine, though only in Word or Excel. Annoyingly, PowerPoint has a bad habit of changing the file to read-only after the error. So the only choice is to save to a new file name.

The issue seems to only happen to files in the user's My Documents, which is a redirection folder from their HomeShare.

The HomeShares are spread across 3 different file servers, 2 Windows 2003 and 1 Windows 2008 R2.

Has anyone seen this issue and know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

One of the more common causes of this is anti-virus locking the file during scans.

Make sure that you're running a version that is supported on Windows 7 and 2008 R2.

Make sure that your clients are set to ignore scanning of network folders (your servers should be scanning files on themselves, the clients shouldn't be scanning over the network).

If you can exclude a directory that is commonly problematic, but that you believe to be safe, that would be a good test to see if it still manifests.

If all else fails, grab a copy of handle.exe from the sysinternals suite and check what has an open handle to the file on the server.